# Ubuntu How to install openvpn 2.3.18

Tags: software-installation, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPN configuration that is working in one (old) PC. Now I wanted to use the same VPN config in another PC (Linux 4.19 Rasberry PI arm7l GNU/Linux).

The problem seems to be due my certificate is too old and new VPN > v2.4 do not longer connect.

I am trying to install the same version as in the old PC (**openVPN 2.3.18**) for Ubuntu distro but unfortunately I cannot find it or do not know how to install an old version.

Can someone point me to the right command/version?

Comment: Ubuntu versions is a requirement. Different Ubuntu versions contain different package versions.

Comment: I'm aware of debian using the 4.19 kernel, I'm unaware of any Ubuntu using it (4.18 was the closest & is now EOL)

Answer (score -1):

Try docker , it's works for me.
My openvpn client could not connect to the server after upgrade ubuntu from 16.04(openvpn 2.3) to ubuntu 18.04(openvpn 2.4.4)

1. install dokcer an docker-composer
2. vi dokcer-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
 services:
   
   openvpn2.3:
     image:  kylemanna/openvpn:2.3
     ports:
       - [OPENVPN PORT DEFINED IN CONFIG FILE]:[SAME]/udp
     volumes:
       - ./data:/data
       - ./run:/var/run/
     entrypoint:
       - openvpn
       - data/[YOU-OLD-OPENVPN-CONFIGFILE].conf
     stdin_open: true
     tty: true
     cap_add:
       - NET_ADMIN
       - SYS_MODULE
     devices:
       - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
```

3. docker-composer up  openvpn2.3

Comment: While this technically works it may lead to other issues if OP can't install docker due to security concerns, etc. on the policies of their environment.  That's the only reason it has a -1 from me.  Also, OP is asking how to *install* the specific OpenVPN in their environment, not asking how to use Docker for that.